# How to know if the keyboard layout changes between numbers and letters?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText where users normaly enter numbers. Therefore I'm using InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER to get a numerical soft keyboard. Occationally though, some users may want to enter letters, so I have a button that switches between InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER  and InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT.

Works fine, but I found that this behaviour becomes very strange on devices with a hardware keyboard. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415558/how-to-detect-hardware-keyboard-presence) that solves that issue, so that I can exclude the keyboard switching functionality for those devices.

But then there are also devices, e.g. my asus transformer prime tablet, that never changes the software keyboard layout when switching between InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER  and InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT. How can i know if the software keyboard will change the layout or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i know if the software keyboard will change the layout or not?

You can't. `InputType` is a hint, not a demand. Some input method editors ("software keyboards") don't even have buttons (see Graffiti). There is no means of interrogating the system to determine the capability of input method editors, largely because the authors of input method editors do not have to declare their capabilities. They can honor or ignore `InputType`, etc. as they see fit.

Comment: Thanks. I also saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100999/android-soft-keyboard-show-numbers-view-first?rq=1